# Toggle extra flexbox div

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

I've created a sharing bar and want to hide some of the less popular options.
The problem is that it's created with the latest and greatest flexbox layout, so ordinary jQuery toggle won't cut it.

How can I solve this issue: `display: none; -> display: flex;` If there is a css-only way that will be appreciated, but any jQuery solution is welcome!

[**Here's a pen with an example of the social div.**](http://codepen.io/Vaia/pen/CLaBK)
As you can see it makes a block, instead of keeping the line (try changing the #more div to display: flex; and see the magic!)

**HTML**

```
<div class="sharing">
<div class="media facebook">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="logo fa fa-facebook"></span>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <span class="text">Share on Facebook</span>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media twitter">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="logo fa fa-twitter"></span>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <span class="text">Share on Twitter</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="more" style="display: none;">
    <div class="media google">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="logo fa fa-google-plus"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media mail">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="logo fa fa-envelope-o"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="media more">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="logo plus">+</span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

**Sass**

```
// vars
$facebook: #3a559f;
$twitter: #00abf0;
$google: #d8412c;
$mail: #ccc;
$more: #eee;
$white: #fff;
$bold: bold;
$border-radius: 4px;

.plus { color: #000; }
.minus { color: #000; }

.sharing {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
padding: 30px 0;

font-size: 11px;
font-weight: $bold;

.media {
    margin: 0 5px;
    min-width: 38px;
    border-radius: $border-radius;

    &.facebook {
        background-color: $facebook;

        .divider {
            background-color: #344c8f;
        }
    }
    &.twitter {
        background-color: $twitter;

        .divider {
            background-color: #009ad8;
        }
    }
    &.google {
        background-color: $google;
    }
    &.mail {
        background-color: $mail;
    }
    &.more {
        background-color: $more;
    }

    a {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        height: 38px;
        color: $white;
        text-decoration: none;

        .logo {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex: 1;
            padding: 0 10px;

            font-size: 17px;
        }
        .divider {
            width: 1px;
            height: 38px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .text {
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $('#more').toggle( function() {
        $('.more span').toggleClass('plus minus');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the css in the these classes

```
&.google {
  background-color: $google;
  display: inline-block;
}
&.mail {
  background-color: $mail;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That does indeed solve the problem UI-wise, but it's not solving my main question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your problem correctly. I tried this on the codepen - and it seems to have worked correctly - however I cannot fork/save my solution there for some reason.

The only change is that I've added

```
#more {
  display:flex;
}
```

under sharing.

Look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y23mp1tc/